# BigQuery - Crashlytics : find all users affected by all issues

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

Taking account that to retrieve all users affected by **a** particular issue, we have to write this query :

```
SELECT user.id as user_id
FROM
  `projectId.firebase_crashlytics.package_name_ANDROID`
WHERE
  issue_id = "YOUR_ISSUE_ID"
  AND application.display_version = ""
  AND user.id != ""
ORDER BY
  user.id;
```

As stated here in the 6th example : https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/bigquery-export#examples_of_crashlytics_queries

---

Which query does retrieve all the users affected by **all** issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to find all the IDs for users affected by any issue - you can write a query like this:

```
SELECT distinct user.id as user_id
FROM
  `projectId.firebase_crashlytics.package_name_ANDROID`
```

You can remove the filters (WHERE clauses) because you want to consider all issues. The DISTINCT clause will remove any duplicates and simply give you one record for each user